# Comparing features with respect to nearest neighbors

Tags: hypothesis-testing, k-nearest-neighbour

I have a following problem.

There is a dataset and two ways of extracting features from examples (let's name the extracted features $X$, $X'$ where $X_i$, $X'_i$ are feature vectors for $i$th example). In my application I perform nearest neighbor search on some of these fatures.

What are methods to find out whether the features $X$, $X'$ are essentially the same (in a sense they give the same results for kNN)?

By "way" I mean (nonparametric) statistical test or something that has underlying theoretical guarantees (for example something that compares distribution of $\| X_i - X_j\|$ and  $\| X'_i - X'_j\|$). I thought of the following ways to compare the features (but it is not clear for me if there are any corresponding statistical tests/rationale for choosing similarity threshold)

- use canonical correlation analysis (the problem is the correspondence with $X$, $X'$ may be nonlinear)
- use PC eigenvalues (the same problem as above?)
- use a dimensionality reduction scheme like MDS (but what? standard MDS on euclidean distance is equivalent to PCA) and then compare outputs visually
- calculate kNN graph for some feasible $k$ and then compare graphs